# Attach ring shaped bead for use as toggle clasp

Tags: jewelry, beads

I'm making a necklace from ring shaped beads, which have two holes through which the beading wire runs diametrically (similar to [these](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32795305746.html)). While all other rings will be filled with other beads, I'd like to keep the last ring open and use it as part of a toggle clasp. However I'm unsure how to attach it.

[image]

So far I have thought of two possible approaches:

1. run the beading wire through one hole, bring it back on the outside and fixate it with crimping beads.

[image]

Disadvantage: beading wire will be visible where it crosses the outside of the bead and this will add extra space between the last ring and the others.

2. Put a headpin through one hole, wrap the outside end into a loop and attach this loop to a loop of the beading wire.

[image]

Disadvantage: adds extra space between the last ring and the others.

So, any suggestions on how to attach the ring bead without adding extra space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can envision a number of approaches to avoid wrapping the wire around the ring and the need for crimping beads.  The exact process would depend on what the beads are made of and how flexible or brittle the wire is.  If the wire is too brittle for some of these solutions, you may be able to use a different type of wire.

**Avoid wrapping the wire around the ring**

- Avoid wrapping the wire around the ring by doing everything through the bead wall.  This would involve either drilling a second hole, so the wire goes in one hole and back out an adjacent hole, or feeding the wire into the bead and back out the same hole.  The hole might need to be enlarged if it isn't already at least twice the diameter of the wire.  The wire loop, alone, may be enough to keep the wire from pulling out of the hole.  If not, you could string a small bead on the wire before putting the end of the wire back through the hole.
- You could also use a headpin, but instead of creating a loop and attaching it to the beading wire, put the end of the pin through the hole in the previous bead (may require enlarging that hole if it will also contain the beading wire).  I'll suggest ways to secure the ends of wire or pin, but you may be able to do your idea #2 inside the next-to-last ring, where it won't add space between the rings.

**Secure the wire or pin without crimping beads**

- Loop or twist the wire around itself.
- Form the end parallel with the wire a short distance and secure it with solder or clear glue.  Variation: whip the end to the wire with very fine wire (optionally solder the whipping).
- After making the loop, push the end of the wire back into the hole in the bead wall and secure it within the wall of the bead.  Depending on the bead material, you may be able to melt the bead to the wire inside the hole (high friction even if the doesn't bond), or wick a drop of superglue into the hole.
- Secure the end of the wire inside the ring wall by wedging a pin in the hole to compress the wire to the hole wall.  If the bead material is not brittle, you can press an appropriately sized pin into the hole with pliers.
- After getting the wire through the bead wall, put a short 90° "L" bend in the end.  Cut a small slot in the bead surface so the "L" can sit below the surface.  If needed, secure it there with a dot of glue, or heat to melt the bead around it.

Comment: Thanks for the good ideas - in particular for mentioning soldering!